# Currently getting a TypeError that states: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'

Tags: python

I'm currently a first year student learning python programming and we are currently working on modules/functions. I am getting an error with my code that reads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/CISC 300 - Dolce/Turn In/A3 Darryl Lardizabal pg121 #4 rework.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/CISC 300 - Dolce/Turn In/A3 Darryl Lardizabal pg121 #4 rework.py", line 81, in main
    yearly = totalYearly (totalMonthly)   File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/CISC 300 - Dolce/Turn In/A3 Darryl Lardizabal pg121 #4 rework.py", line 50, in totalYearly
    totalYearly = totalMonthly*ONE_YEAR TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'
```

I have tried to play with the line in multiple ways including totatYearly=totalMonthly * 12 and so forth and so on, but not sure if it's just there or what else may be wrong with the code.

```
def totalYearly (totalMonthly):
    totalYearly = totalMonthly*ONE_YEAR
    return totalYearly
```

Thank you for your help!

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:         Darryl Lardizabal
# Date:         2-20-2017
# Reference:    Chapter 3      page # 121   problem # 4
# Title:    Auto Costs
# Constants:    ONE_YEAR = 12.0
# Inputs:   Monthly Costs for Loan Payment, Insurance, Gas, Oil, Tires, Maintenance.
# ProcessA: Calculate sum for both monthly and annual costs of loan payment,
# ProcessB:     insurance, gas, oil, tires, and maintenance.
# Outputs:  Monthly Costs and Annual Costs 
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#GLOBAL CONSTANTS
ONE_YEAR = 12.0

##The following modules gets the cost of monthly expenses and stores it in the getCost
#reference variable ----------------------------------------------------------------------
def getLP ():
    loanPayment = float(input("Please enter your monthly loan payment: "))
    return loanPayment

def getInsurance ():
    insurance = float(input("Please enter how much you spend on your insurance per month: "))
    return insurance

def getGas ():
    gas = float(input("Please enter how much you spend on gas per month: "))
    return gas

def getOil ():
    oil = float(input("Please enter how much you buy in oil per month: "))
    return oil

def getTires ():
    tires = float(input("Please enter how much you spend on tires each month: "))
    return tires

def getMaintenance ():
    maintenance = float(input("Please enter how much you spend on maintenance per month: "))
    return maintenance

##The totalMonthly module adds the cost of the monthly expenses and stores it in the
#totalMonthly reference variable ---------------------------------------------------------
def totalMonthly (loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance):
    totalMonthly = loanPayment + insurance + gas + oil + tires + maintenance
    return totalMonthly

##The totalYearly module adds the costs of the monthly expenses and multiples it by 12 and
#stores it in the totalYearly module reference variable ----------------------------------
def totalYearly (totalMonthly):
    totalYearly = totalMonthly*ONE_YEAR
    return totalYearly

##The showCosts module shows the total monthly and total yearly costs for the individual --
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def showCosts (monthly, yearly):
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
    print ("Drum Roll Please...")
    print (".........................................................")
    print ("Your total monthly costs are: ", format(monthly,".2f"))
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
    print ("Your total yearly costs are: ", format(yearly,".2f"))
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------")
    return

##main module
def main():
    print ("-------------Starting Main-------------------------------")
    ## Get Monthly Costs from User
    loanPayment = getLP()
    insurance = getInsurance()
    gas = getGas()
    oil = getOil()
    tires = getTires ()
    maintenance = getMaintenance()


    ##Calculate Monthly Costs of User
    monthly = totalMonthly (loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance)

    ##Calculate Annual Costs of User
    yearly = totalYearly (totalMonthly)

    ##Show Costs to User for both per month and per year
    showCosts (totalMonthly, totalYearly)

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calculating the yearly value and displaying the results you're passing functions instead of their results as parameter. Fix that and it will work:

```
##Calculate Monthly Costs of User
monthly = totalMonthly (loanPayment, insurance, gas, oil, tires, maintenance)

##Calculate Annual Costs of User
#yearly = totalYearly (totalMonthly)
yearly = totalYearly (monthly)

##Show Costs to User for both per month and per year
#showCosts (totalMonthly, totalYearly)
showCosts (monthly, yearly)
```

**Update** Here's a short example of what's happening now and how the above fixes it:

```
>>> def totalMonthly(x):
...     return x + 1
... 
>>> def totalYearly(monthly):
...     return monthly * 12
... 
>>> m = totalMonthly(3)
>>> totalYearly(totalMonthly)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in totalYearly
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'
>>> totalYearly(m)
48
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still fairly new to this. I understand that I'm passing functions, but not sure how to input the results instead. 

Thanks so far niemmi.

Comment: @DarrylLardizabal The changes above will pass the results instead of functions. If you replace the relevant place from your code with above it will work as you expect. I added short example to illustrate what's happening and how the change fixes that.